# Java Instance of: Supertypes and Subtypes seem to be equal? How to test exactly for Type?

Tags: java, instanceof

I need to test, if an instance is exactly of a given type. But it seems that instanceof returns true also if the subtype is tested for the supertype (case 3). I never knew this before and I am quite surprised. Am I doing something wrong here? How do I exactly test for a given type?

```
//..

class DataSourceEmailAttachment extends EmailAttachment

//...

EmailAttachment emailAttachment = new EmailAttachment();
DataSourceEmailAttachment emailAttachmentDS = new DataSourceEmailAttachment();

    if (emailAttachment instanceof EmailAttachment){
        System.out.println(" 1");
    }
    if (emailAttachment instanceof DataSourceEmailAttachment){
        System.out.println(" 2");
    }

    if (emailAttachmentDS instanceof EmailAttachment){
        System.out.println(" 3 ");
    }
    if (emailAttachmentDS instanceof DataSourceEmailAttachment){
        System.out.println(" 4");
    }
```

RESULT:

```
 1
 3 
 4
```

**I want to avoid case 3**, I only want "exact matches" (case 1 and 4) how do I test for them?

Comment: @jens: usually things like *getClass()* and *instanceof* (besides in the *equals* method) are huge code smell (unless you're writing some framework). Polymorphism can very probably be used to do what you think you need to do by using *getClass()* and/or *instanceof*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if( emailAttachment.getClass().equals(EmailAttachment.class) )
```

Comment: Hello marcos. Thanks, I learned a lot! I was never aware that I have to test for classes if I need exact matches. Thanks!